# Connecting to a Restful Web Service using Basic Authentication

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to make a request from a RWS and I am constantly getting the `401 not authorized error`

I have been provided a sample username and password for testing purposes but I have a feeling my implementation is off.  This is my first foray into the world of RWS.

```
class Program
    {
        static string _address = "https://this.istheservice/";

        static async void RunClient()
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            handler.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Sample", "P@ssw0rd!!");

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

            // Send asynchronous request
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);

            // Check that response was successful or throw exception
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();//Breaks here
```

When I inspected the NetworkCredentials the Domain was listed as `Domain = ""` would this cause an issue?

If I drop the URL they provide into a browser I get 401 error as well.

If more information is needed please ask, I am not sure what moving parts need to be included here.

I am working from this example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/17/downloading-a-google-map-to-local-file.aspx and I am using Fiddler to monitor the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your trying to do there is not basic authentication.
To do basic Authentication you need to base64 encrypt username:password and put them in the header

```
   string basic = "Basic ENCRYPTEDSTRING";
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", basic);
```

So your header should have something like this when you see it in fiddler

Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

Wiki link to basic authentication http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Would this `string basic = "Basic ENCRYPTEDSTRING"` be something that the client would provide to me or would plugging in the code above work in my application?

Comment: in your example you would base64 encrypt "Sample=P@ssw0rd!!" which is U2FtcGxlPVBAc3N3MHJkISE=

Comment: you can use an online tool if you want http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/

Comment: So use the line string basic = "Basic U2FtcGxlPVBAc3N3MHJkISE=";

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work, the credentials they gave me may just be no good. Will update this item once I recieve verification they are correct.

Comment: Reading over the wiki its a : not an = sorry you'll have to recalculate the string

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this as well. I believe my client has provided me with improper credentials as nothing is working and i'm receiving 401 errors. Once this gets reconciled I will accept your answer as correct if it solves my problem.